# Laravel - 404 Not Found when trying any endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I have just created a Laravel project and testing the first endpoint through Insomnia, however, this always returns 404.

In the project directory, I have installed `valet` and used its URL, which then returns 404 whenever I run a request through Insomnia.

Also when I run `valet open` from the project directory this opens a web page with the Laravel main page which makes me think that `valet` is working fine.

[image: the URL in the URL field is the one I am using on Insomnia]

api.php

```
Route::group([
  'middleware' => 'api',
  'prefix' => 'auth'
], function ($router) {
  Route::post('register', 'AuthController@registerUser');
  Route::get('', 'AuthController@testing');
});
```

AuthController.php

```
public function registerUser()
{
  return response()->json('User signed up');
}

public function testing()
{
  return response()->json('Test ok');
}
```

The snipped code above is the route that I currently have in place which should simply go to the AuthController file and run the registerUser method.

Whatever I am doing on Insomnia is:

[image]

Comment: what other end points have you tried? can you show what you are doing in that controller method .. where did you register this route?

Comment: @lagbox In the functions, I am just returning a message just to make sure that at least the request goes through, and btw I have also updated the question.

Comment: you are saying all end points return 404, what other end points did you try? and where did you define this route you have above?

Comment: So the first one is /auth/register POST request, and the second one is /auth GET request, both returning 404, they are both defined in the api.php file. Please see at the post updated, all the info are there

Comment: missing `'` on AuthController.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes are probably not for the URLs you think they are. They are probably:

```
mentorme-api.test/api/auth
mentorme-api.test/api/auth/register
```

The `routes/api.php` file gets loaded in a route group with prefix `api` for you.

Run `php artisan route:list` from the command line to see how your routes have been registered.

The group definition the `routes/api.php` routes get loaded into:

```
Route::prefix('api')
     ->middleware('api')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Prefixed with `api` and already have the `api` middleware applied. You can remove `'middleware' => 'api'` from your group definition for your 2 routes.

Comment: You're right, by including api in the url this goes through, God, I went mental for a while! Thank you buddy

Comment: no problem ... how these route files get registered is in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` btw

Comment: Yeah, I just made changes in the file, and is all good! Thank you again!